# Making a Web API method accept an xml

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API so if this question sounds trivial or stupid please still give a solution.

I have a requirement where the consumer of my web api wants to post an xml.

I created an empty Web API controller and added a method like so:

```
public class StudentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Student GetStudent(Student studentXml)
    {
        Student student = new Student() { Id = 502, Course = "Chemistry" };
        return student;
    }
}
```

The param is of type Student which is the class that has the same properties as the tags in the xml.
The XML that will be posted is like so:

```
<StudentStatus>
    <AccountID>1231</AccountID>
    <Password>2132132</Password>
    <Batch/>
    <Sequence/>
    <Test>0</Test>
    <Date>09/25/2014 09:18:24</Date>
    <TestNumber>1972</TestNumber>
    <StatusCode>3</StatusCode>
    <ID>502</ID>
</StudentStatus>
```

The method is suppose to return an XML in response. 
That's easy with the

> Accept: application/xml

But how do I make the method accept an XML?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Use [HttpPost] for posting the xml as string. Convert the XML to dataset (ds.ReadXML)

Comment: Added HttpPost as the attribute and passed the XML as string, browser says "length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value"

Comment: Do not Pass it with the URL. Pass it using Jquery post method

Comment: You can do post using WebRequest also in .net

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller code...Remove Get Prefix, no need to add [HttpPost]
Put a breakpint to see if it hits there.

```
public void PostStudent(string studentXml)
    {
       //Write your logic here
    }
```

Try this in the code from where you are posting data

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
var data = "XML data" //Try HTML.Encode if it does not work               
var result = client.UploadString("http://localhost:52996/api/Student", "POST", data);
//Do something with result
}
```

Comment: So the method is marked HttpGet and the WebClient call is POST, that doesn't work. Changed the method to use HttpPost and it give 404. I can post the controller code if you want. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Try Reading this also...http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Comment: Added the code with the Object that the method expects.

Comment: Check out this link also...http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client